# lexical error in string/charcter literal at character ' '?

Tags: string, list, haskell

I am a newbie to Haskell and am trying to cipher the plain text by using `shifting` the ASCII values and if my plain text contains a number,then it has to encode each digit by putting a special symbol in place of the digit like `(0=*,1=',2=~,3=!,4=@,5=#,6=$, 7=%,8=^,9=&)`. so here is my code for encryption

```
import Data.Char

canEncrypt :: Char -> Bool
canEncrypt c = isLower(c) && isAscii(c)

encryptChar :: Char -> Char -> Char
encryptChar shift c
 | canEncrypt c = chr(ord(c)+ord(shift))
 | isUpper c = c
 | isNumber c = if (c == 0) then '*'
                 else if (c == 1) then '\'
                       else if (c == 2) then '~'
                             else if (c == 3) then '!'
                                   else if (c == 4) then '@'
                                         else if (c==5) then '#'
                                               else if (c==6) then '$'
                                                     else if (c==7) then '%'
                                                           else if (c==8) then '^'
                                                                 else '&'
```

and yeah it's a little spaghetti code but when I compiling it it showing an error like below

```
    |
    | lexical error in string/character literal at character ' '
21  | isNumber c = blah blah blah..
    |
```

I think am doing something terribly wrong here that I don't know what.so don't hesitate for such silly question am a just beginner so any help would be appreciated and also is there any other implementation to implement this kind of `if-else` problem?
Thank you

Comment: Also, in future please don't edit or abbreviate error messages when you're asking for help resolving an error. Even if it's meaningless gibberish to *you*, they contain information that the people you're asking to help you can use to help you. For example, this one would have contained the exact character position of the lexical error it was complaining about.

Comment: Style comment: you can use a `case` instead of that `if` chain. `case c of '0' -> '*' ; '1' -> '\\' ; ...`. You can indent all the cases on the same column. You can also use multiple defining equations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You write:

```
else if (c == 1) then '\'
```

Based on your question, you want to return a quote (`'`). You do this by escaping the quote, but you need an end of char marker. So we should write `'\''`

```
else if (c == 1) then '\''
```

That being said, this is a nice cascade of `if`-`then`-`else`s.

Since `c` is a `Char`, you can not perform a `c == 1`, since the equivalence function `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool` thus compares two `a`s (so the same type). So we need to write it like:

```
else if (c == '1') then '\''
```

Now we have a long cascade of `if`-`then`-`else`s. This is not very elegant, and hard to understand. We can use *pattern matching* for this:

```
encryptChar :: Char -> Char -> Char
encryptChar shift c
 | canEncrypt c = chr (ord c + ord shift)
 | isUpper c = c
encryptChar _ '0' = '*'
encryptChar _ '1' = '\''
encryptChar _ '2' = '~'
encryptChar _ '3' = '!'
encryptChar _ '4' = '@'
encryptChar _ '5' = '#'
encryptChar _ '6' = '$'
encryptChar _ '7' = '%'
encryptChar _ '8' = '^'
encryptChar _ '9' = '&'
```

We can also define a list of values, a list of `Char`s is a `String`:

```
digittrans = "*'~!@#$%^&"
```

and then we can lookup the *i*-th index with: `digittrans !! i`. So by parsing a string "4" to the `Int` counterpart with `read "4"`, we can obtain the correct value:

```
encryptChar :: Char -> Char -> Char
encryptChar shift c
 | canEncrypt c = chr (ord c + ord shift)
 | isUpper c = c
 | isDigit c = digittrans !! read [c]
    where digittrans = "*'~!@#$%^&"
```

We also need to think of a resultion mechanism in case all the above checks fail (something is not encryptable, nor uppercase, nor a digit). In that case we can for instance decide to return the character itself:

```
encryptChar :: Char -> Char -> Char
encryptChar shift c
 | canEncrypt c = chr (ord c + ord shift)
 | isUpper c = c
 | isDigit c = digittrans !! read [c]
    where digittrans = "*'~!@#$%^&"
encryptChar _ c = c
```

Comment: what about `| isNumber c = dict !! read [c] where dict = "*'~!@#$%^&"` instead of this huge pattern-match?

Answer (score 5):

Here's your problem:

```
if (c == 1) then '\'
```

The backslash is a special character in string and character literals; it's used to escape the following character, so that you can use *other* special characters inside string and character literals.

So `'\'` is read by the Haskell parser as a single quote beginning a character literal, followed by a backslash-escaped single quote *inside* the character literal, but then there's no unescaped single quote to properly end the character literal, which is why it complains that the next character is a "lexical error in string/character literal".

If you're trying to write a character literal for the backslash character, then you need to use a backslash to escape the backslash to have Haskell read it as a backslash *in* a character literal, rather than a backslash modifying the interpretation of the next character. So: `'\\'`

If you're trying to write a character literal for a single quote character, then you had the backslash-escaped single quote character correct for the quote *inside* the character literal, but you still need to add a non-escaped quote to terminate the character literal. So: `'\''`